# ProgressBar flet

Tags: progress-bar, flet

Someone knows how to disable the progressBar on Flet?

```
    pb = ft.ProgressBar(width=700, color="red", bgcolor="#eeeeee")
```

I already read https://flet.dev/docs/controls/progressbar/ but I don't find a propety that could work to deactivate and activate it

To deactivate the progressBar and activate when I want to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All flet controls have a show/hide attribute. See here for more [information](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/#visible). flet samples can be modified so that the progress bar is hidden when the screen is activated, but can be displayed by clicking a button.

```
from time import sleep

import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    pb = ft.ProgressBar(width=400, visible=False)

    def start(e):
        pb.visible=True
        for i in range(0, 101):
            pb.value = i * 0.01
            sleep(0.1)
            page.update()
            
    page.add(
        ft.Text("Linear progress indicator", style="headlineSmall"),
        ft.ElevatedButton("Indicator start", on_click=start),
        ft.Column([ ft.Text("Doing something..."), pb]),
    )

ft.app(target=main)
```